# Intermittent 'Error 403 - This web app is stopped'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

A multi-instance Standard Azure website calls itself (via ASP Web API) to use the razor engine to render an email template. Since yesterday (site has been live 2 years) the api is is occasionally (1 in 20) returning

> Error 403 - This web app is stopped.
>
> The web app you have attempted to reach is currently stopped and does
>   not accept any requests. Please try to reload the page or visit it
>   again soon.
>
> If you are the Administrator of this web app, please visit the Azure
>   Portal to check why the app is stopped.

It should return a nice 'Thank you for your order' message.

Looking in the (mostly baffling to me) Kudo interface there is no indication that the website actually stopped/restarted. If it did I think I would at least see the WebJobs firing up in the logs? (not sure about this actually). The IIS Logs don't show any break in the service.

I'm not sure what I should be looking to do to resolve this issue?

I'll try a Slot Swap and report back...

edit: Deployed new version to stage, swapped. Error persists. This pattern (hit api for rendered html, then email it) is used several times but it's only this one url that has this issue. Odd.

Comment: Could you clarify what hosting plan you are using for the site.

Comment: It's a 'Standard' tier with 2  instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The live site had two (stopped) deployment slots. As soon as I deleted these slots the problem stopped.

I guess the load balancer was incorrectly sending requests to an instance that had been swapped and stopped, and deletion forced the LB to update something?

Will monitor for another 24 hours or so before accepting this as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Is the Web App running in Free/Shared mode? 
If yes, then it might exceeded the quota applicable to it.